# How do I configure my Microsoft Access database to pull source data directly from SAP BW?

Tags: database, ms-access, netweaver, sap-bw

I use several Microsoft Access databases on a regular basis to create reports. To get the source data, I currently have to log in to SAP BW (via SAP NetWeaver), run the source data report, export the results as a .csv file (but actually saving it as a .txt file), and then import that file into Microsoft Access. Is there a way that I can have Access pull the data from SAP BW directly?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

All of the databases used by SAP are industry standard databases and the data is thus going to be stored in a system that supports ODBC.

As far as I know, SAP in general uses Sybase which is also what SQL server was originally based on.

So SAP is running on an industry standard SQL server (Sybase or SQL server). If running on IBM, then the data is in DB2 (often the as400 system).

You thus simply need to contact your IT department and obtain the required ODBC connection strings to the database. You “might” also need to install the latest Sybase drivers if you not running SAP on SQL server but again such information would be available from your SAP support folks.

So you simply setup linked tables in access to the SAP database, and thus no export or download or importing of data is required – you be reporting on live data at all times. The “challenge” is thus of course to grasp the table structures in SAP - a LARGE challenge since in most cases a report you been using for exports is the result of MANY related tables joined together into a "easy" view for exporting.  So be prepared for some complex quires to get the data the way you want.