# Importing .csv to MS Access. "AtEndOfStream" doesn't read last line

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, vbscript

I want to import some data from a .csv file into a MS Access database via VBScript.

```
Sub CSVImport
  connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=P:\somedatabase.accdb"

  'Define object type
  Set objConn      = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  'Open Connection
  objConn.open connStr

  objRecordSet.Open "SELECT * FROM SomeTable", _
    objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("P:\someFile.csv")

  Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strVKBL_Stamm = objFile.ReadLine
    arrVKBL_Stamm = Split(strVKBL_Stamm, ";")
    objRecordSet.AddNew

    objRecordSet("FirstName") = arrVKBL_Stamm(0)
    objRecordSet("LastName")  = arrVKBL_Stamm(1)
    objRecordSet("Date")      = arrVKBL_Stamm(...)
    objRecordSet("Type")      = arrVKBL_Stamm(11)
  Loop

  Set objRecordSet = Nothing
  Set objFSO = Nothing
  Set objFile = Nothing
  Set objConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

This script gets all the data out of my CSV file but it does miss the last line. When I hit return twice (once doesn't suffice) at the end of the .csv all of my data gets imported.

My backup plan is to change the `AtEndOfStream` bit to something like

```
If arrVKBL_Stamm(0) = 0 Then
  Exit Do
```

and add a zero to the file. Problem is, the .csv is a report, exported from SAP (which is - afaik - unable to export to MS Access itself), so that part would need another script or has to be done by hand.

Does anyone have a clue or give me a hint how to solve this?

Comment: The code you posted would raise errors, not only because of the missing `End Sub`, but because you're trying to modify a closed recordset. Please show your actual code.

Comment: Added the rest, not sure if this clarifies things. But I hope so. :)

Comment: Your code still cannot work. You never open a file, you never add a new record in `objRecordSet`. [mcve]

Comment: Stupid me, edited that part out, the code was a bit cluttered because of some error catching-blocks. It's in  there now. Sorry.

Comment: And how do you open your file? // sigh

Comment: Oh man.. sorry. I'm really not concentrated right now. It should (finally) be all in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\myfile.csv", 1)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    S = objFile.ReadLine
    Debug.Print S
Loop
objFile.Close
```

in VBA and it printed **all** lines of my CSV file, even if the last line doesn't end with a CrLf.

I'm pretty sure the reason is: your `objRecordSet.AddNew` is missing an `objRecordSet.Update`.

Apparently, if you call `.AddNew` after the previous `.AddNew`, the previous record is saved nevertheless.

But `objRecordSet.AddNew` followed by `Set objRecordSet = Nothing` doesn't save the last record.

Solution: add `objRecordSet.Update` as last command in the loop.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help especially with regard to the long process of asking the right question. (;

Answer (score 0):

SAP uses a standard database engine in the back end. You can set up linked tables that pull directly from SAP in to Access. No export\import. It's a live table.

**SEE HERE:**

[How do I configure my Microsoft Access database to pull source data directly from SAP BW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519266/how-do-i-configure-my-microsoft-access-database-to-pull-source-data-directly-fro)

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1382889